# how to disable the user to click action column mulitple times when one event is still in progress extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6, sencha-architect, extjs6-classic

I have a action column and I am disabling it on some condition and have a handler to it to make the ajax call. But I want to restrict the user or making multiple calls until one call is completed. I dont want the user to double click the the icon when already clicked.

ViewController method:

```
    processDone: function (record) {
    //debugger;
    var me = this;
    var detailRecs = me.getStore('WarrantyDetail').data.items;
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(record) && (detailRecs.length > 0)) {
        canProcess = false;
        Ext.Array.forEach(detailRecs, function (r) {
            if (r.data.facilityId == 9 || r.data.amount == 0 || 
         Ext.isEmpty(record.data.qeContact)) {
                canProcess = true;

            }
        });
        if (canProcess) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid detail line item ');
            return;
        }        
        var detailLineAmt = me.getStore('WarrantyDetail').sum('amount');
        detailLineAmt = Math.abs(detailLineAmt);
        var headerAmount = Math.abs(record.data.amount)
       //if (me.getStore('WarrantyDetail').sum('amount') > 

     Math.abs(record.data.amount)){
            if (detailLineAmt > headerAmount){//added to check for range
               Ext.Msg.alert('Sum of Detail Amount must not be more than `
            Header Amount ');`
            return;
        }

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: webContext + 'url',
            success: function (response) {
                me.getStore('WarrantyHeader').reload();
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                me.getStore('WarrantyHeader').reload();
            }
        });
        this.getViewModel().set('currentHeader', null);
    } else if (!Ext.isEmpty(record) && (detailRecs.length == 0)) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Please add atleast one detail lineItem');
    }
}
```

Action column

```
if (this.showDone) {
Ext.Array.insert(this.columns, 0, [{
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 30,
                minWidth: 30,
                resizable: false,
                menuDisabled: true,
                items: [{
                    icon: 'resources/images/icons/approve_icon.png', 
                    tooltip: 'Flag Record as Done',
                    stopSelection: false,

                    handler: function (tableview, rowIndex) {
                        var rec = tableview.grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                        if (rec.data.qualityDone) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if 
(!tableview.grid.getSelectionModel().isSelected(rec)) {
                            tableview.grid.getSelectionModel().select(rec);
                            Ext.Function.defer(function () {
                                tableview.grid.doDone(rec);
                            }, 250);
                        } else {
                            tableview.grid.doDone(rec);
                        }

                    },
                    isDisabled: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, 
                item,record) {
                        var done = record.data.qualityDone;
                        if (FACTT.app.isQualityUser()) {
                            return done;
                        } else if (FACTT.app.isARUser() && done) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }],
                renderer: function (value, meta, record, row, column, store, 
                    view) {
                    /* To conditionally hide the icon specified in the icon 
                          config above. eg */
                    var colItem1 = meta.column.items[0],
                        imgPath = 'resources/images/icons';

                    if (!record.data.qualityDone) {

                        //colItem1.disabled = false;
                        if (!record.data.qualityDone && 
                       FACTT.app.isARUser()) {
                            colItem1.icon = imgPath + 
                                    '/padlock_unlockedgray.png';
                        } else {
                            colItem1.icon = imgPath + 
                            '/padlock_unlocked.png';
                            colItem1.tooltip = 'Click here to complete & 
                 submit the record to AR';
                        }
                    } else if (record.data.qualityDone && 
                  FACTT.app.isARUser()) {
                        colItem1.icon = imgPath + '/padlock_lockedblue.png';
                        colItem1.tooltip = 'Header record is Locked. Please 
                   click on the Detail record to create an adjustment';

                    } else {
                        colItem1.icon = imgPath + '/padlock_locked2.png';
                        colItem1.tooltip = 'Header record is Locked';

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Didnt you show mask on grid itself ?

Comment: I tried masking in the handler but still two calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

In action column set a flag property for your record and when your ajax return response set it back to default And when you want call the ajax check that flag property.
For example in your action column handler:

```
handler: function (tableview, rowIndex) {
       var rec = tableview.grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
       if(!rec.ajaxFlag){
            //call your ajax here...
            rec.ajaxFlag = true;
       } 
}
```

And in your ajax do this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: webContext + 'url',
        success: function (response) {
            record.ajaxFlag = false;//set flag to false
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            record.ajaxFlag = false;//set flag to false
        }
});
```